# Javascript underscore.js- do I have to use a context parameter and 'this'?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this

In a tutorial I'm watching on underscore this code is used to demonstrate `_.each`:

```
var people = {
    names: ['Craig', 'John', 'Dan', 'Elijah'],
    getMessage: function(name) {
      return 'Hello there, ' + name + '!';
    }
};

_.each(people.names, function(element, index, list) {
  console.log(this.getMessage(element))
}, people);
```

It's explained that `people` gets passed as the context for the `_.each` call to bind `this` to the `people` object but I don't understand why this is necessary. In the body of the iterator function couldn't I just explicitly write out `people.getMessage` ?

like:

```
_.each(people.names, function(element, index, list) {
  console.log(people.getMessage(element));
});
```

Why use `this` and have to pass in a context at all?

Comment: Because then the function can be generalized to apply to any object rather than one specific object.

Comment: _why this is necessary_ This is unnecessary, but very useful

Comment: "Context" is a much abused term in javascript. Replace the phrase "*as the context for*" with the word "to" and perhaps it makes more sense. It would also be more correct to say "*people* is assigned to the function's *this*", because that's what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, it is not necessary but it can be useful in certain cases. It also keeps the iterator function unaware of the scope above. It only knows it's dealing with objects that have a `getMessage()` method and not linked to a specific variable in the closure.

One example i can think of is to be able to reuse that for different objects that have the same sort of structure but are not named `people` in the scope.

```js
var people = {
    names: ['Craig', 'John', 'Dan', 'Elijah'],
    getMessage: function(name) {
      return 'Hello there, ' + name + '!';
    }
};

var dogs = {
  names: ['Jimmy', 'Rufus', 'Woofie', 'Silly'],
  getMessage: function(name) {
      return 'Woof there, ' + name + '!';
    }
};

function logTheMessage(element) {
  console.log(this.getMessage(element));
}

_.each(people.names, logTheMessage, people);
_.each(people.names, logTheMessage, dogs);
```